# Xcode-select not found

Tags: xcode, select

any Xcode-select command i write the output is like this

> ASSs-MacBook-Pro:~ abdu505llah$ xcode-select -v
>
> -bash: xcode-select: command not found

or

> ASSs-MacBook-Pro:~ abdu505llah$ xcode-select --install
>
> -bash: xcode-select: command not found

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed?

Comment: yes i do also the Xcode-select was in my mac

Comment: What is the value returned when you execute the command `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Also, which version of Xcode do you have installed?

Comment: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: Xcode 5.02 and my mac os 10.9

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Xcode installed, then you'll need to install Xcode for this command to be available. (Xcode is available through the App Store application.)

If you do have Xcode installed by this command still isn't available, then there is probably something wrong with your `PATH` environment variable. You'll need to set up `PATH` so that it includes `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: The `PATH` variable is normally set in your `.bash_login` or `.bashrc` file. From your response it appears that there are invalid invisible characters in your `PATH`. Your `/opt/local/sbin` and `/usr/bin` sections. You need to update the file where the `PATH` variable is set to remove those values. Those characters were probably added when the file was edited. You should then start a new terminal session to get the updated `PATH` variable.

Comment: i can't find this files  .bash_login or  .bashrc

Comment: These files are not visible in the Finder, but they are in your user home directory. `cd` in Terminal to go to home, then use `ls -a` and you should see the file listed. Then use `open <filename>` to open the file and edit it. You've probably edited the file before because those invalid characters probably are there due to editing.

Comment: this is the invisible files
..
.CFUserTextEncoding
.DS_Store
.TVUPlayer for MacOS X
.Trash
.adobe
.bash_history
.bash_profile
.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-12-03_at_19:46:18
.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-12-26_at_23:31:24
.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-12-27_at_04:10:38
.cobaltstrike.prop
.config
.crossftp
.dtLiteMacLicense.dat
.filezilla
.fonts.cache-1
.gem
.local
.pgpass
.profile
.rnd
.shsh
.spotflux
.subversion
.swt
.ts3client
.viminfo
.webrenderer

Comment: If you don't have a favorite editor you can just use `open -a textedit .bash_profile` to open the file in TextEdit. Then look at where `PATH` is set and clear out the invalid characters.

Comment: the invalid characters that you told me /opt/local/sbin and /usr/bin ?

Comment: Yes, just delete the values that are there and retype the correct values.

Comment: After you've made the changes and saved the file. The easiest way is to open a new Terminal window. In that new window `xcode-select` should work correctly.

Comment: I did everything you said and the result was                        ASSs-MacBook-Pro:~ 'abdu505llah$ xcode-select'
          '-bash: xcode-select: command not found'

Comment: What is the value returned when you execute the command `echo $PATH` now?